# Using CASE Statement with two strings in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression, calculate-values

I am trying to fill out a field based on information in a different field in the same layer using a CASE Statement in the Field Calculator. My table structure looks like this:

| SPECIES | SHORT |
| --- | --- |
| Toad | NULL |
| NULL | B |
| Fish | NULL |
| Plant | NULL |

My goal looks like this:

| SPECIES | SHORT |
| --- | --- |
| Toad | T |
| NULL | B |
| Fish | F |
| Plant | P |

The Expression I am using and does not work looks like this:

```sql
CASE  
   WHEN "Species" LIKE 'Toad' THEN 'T'  
   WHEN "Species" LIKE 'Fish' THEN 'F'  
   WHEN "Species" LIKE 'Plant' THEN 'P'  
END
```

The result is that everything in `"SHORT"` ends up being `NULL`.

The Field `"SPECIES"` is a VALUE MAP widget type. `"SHORT"` is a TEXT EDIT.
I am using QGIS 3.1

Comment: Edit to the Expression: It's "SPECIES" not "Species" just like in the table above

Comment: Try using a wildcard. Like `WHEN "Species" LIKE '%Toad%' THEN 'T'`. Otherwise, if you are looking for an exact match, dont use `LIKE`, but `=` instead, e.g. `WHEN "Species" = 'Toad' THEN 'T'`

Comment: I'm not sure if it was in 3.1 or if it came later, but since the field is a value map, wouldn't OP need to use `represent_value("Species") = 'Toad'` in the expression for it to work?

Comment: As an aside, there is no inherent cost difference between using `LIKE ...` and `regexp_match`.  If anything, the latter is slightly faster since `LIKE` is translated to a regex before evaluation.  Source: reading the QGIS source code.  (correct me if I'm misremembering this).

Answer (score 8):

To get the same result you can use even a simpler formula with [`left()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#left) to get the first letter only.

```
left("SPECIES", 1)
```

Answer (score 7):

using wildcards [`%`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) like `'%Toad%'` worked for me.

My Expression now looks like this:

```sql
CASE  
   WHEN "SPECIES" LIKE '%Toad%' THEN 'T'  
   WHEN "SPECIES" LIKE '%Fish%' THEN 'F'  
   WHEN "SPECIES" LIKE '%Plant%' THEN 'P'  
   ELSE "SHORT"
END
```

I added the `ELSE "SHORT"` to prevent attributes to be lost if `"SPECIES" is NULL`